# Django Register Form 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'

Tags: django

I have the following register view that enters a new user.
I want it to enter the new user and then log in automatically.
It saves through the User record but returns this error when trying to login:
'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'

views.py

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST, error_class=DivErrorList)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            new_user = authenticate(username=request.POST['username'],password=request.POST['password'])
            login(request, new_user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/production/')
    else:
        form = UserRegisterForm(error_class=DivErrorList)

    return render(request,'register.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

forms.py

```
class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','first_name','last_name','email','password')

    password_compare = forms.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserRegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['password_compare'].label = 'Password Again'
        self.fields['password'].help_text = ''
        self.fields['first_name'].label = 'First Name'
        self.fields['last_name'].label = 'Last Name'
        self.fields['email'].label = 'E-mail Address'

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        password1 = cleaned_data.get('password', None)
        password2 = cleaned_data.get('password_compare', None)
        if not (password1):
            error_msg = u'This field is required.'
            self._errors['password'] = self.error_class([error_msg])
        if not (password2):
            error_msg = u'This field is required.'
            self._errors['password_compare'] = self.error_class([error_msg])
        # password fields must match
        if password1 != password2:
            error_msg = u'Password doesn\'t match the confirmation.'
            self._errors['password'] = self.error_class([error_msg])
            del cleaned_data['password']
        # cannot have a username already existing
        try:
            existing_user = User.objects.get(username=cleaned_data.get('username'))
            error_msg = u'Username already exists.'
            self._errors['username'] = self.error_class([error_msg])
            del cleaned_data['username']
            return cleaned_data
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your user will never authenticate, because you're saving the password in plain text - and `authenticate` expects a hashed password. You should call `user.set_password(password)` on the newly-created user object before saving it to the db - see the [built-in `UserCreationForm`](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/contrib/auth/forms.py#L13).

Comment: Thank you so much. Looking at the built-in UserCreationForm pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: User(attr...) saves password in plaintext as well whereas User.objects.create_user(attr...) hashes the password for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error for a newly registering user and it left me frustrated for an hour.

There was a piece of code that tried to log user in right after the registration.
Usually it worked just fine, but not this time.

```
def attempt_login(self, email, password):
    user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
    login(self.request, user)

    return user
```

It seemed that `authenticate` returned `None`, and then calling `login` with `None` caused this exception. But I was sure the `User` has been created after registration.

Finally, I realized that this particular user's login was **longer than 30 characters**, and the form field had no validation. The login would [get truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915910/django-auth-user-truncating-email-field) in the database, and therefore `authenticate` was called for non-existent login.