# Django App Engine: AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I am using djangoappengine. When I try create a new user, authenticate that user, and log them in, I get the following error `AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'`.

My code is simple and looks like:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username, username, password)
user.set_password(password)
user.save()

user = django.contrib.auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
django.contrib.auth.login(request, user)
```

I only get the following error on production and only occasionally:

```
web req_create: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~XXXXX/1.356802202883392818/XXXX/XXX.py", line 332, in req_create
    login(request, user)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~XXXXX/1.356802202883392818/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 82, in login
    request.session[BACKEND_SESSION_KEY] = user.backend
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'
```

I am not sure, but I have a bad feeling that this exception is due to the high replication data store and its eventual consistency. I think that `authenticate()` saves the user value and that `login()` does a query but the user value has not yet propagated into the HRDS. Can anyone confirm this to be true? If so, how would it be fixed?

Comment: Please past the original error with traceback.

Answer (score 3):

When you save the user it will be not activate automatically. Please check the link for [AnonymousUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser) which says how your user become `AnonymousUser`.

So you have to set all items which may be make your user as `AnonymousUser`. Before authenticate please check `user.is_anonymous()`.

Comment: I don't think so. As you can see in the code above, I create the user and authenticate it before trying to log in. It should not be an anonymous user.

Comment: yes but please check the `is_anonymous()`. When you create the user it will not automatically `active` so please make sure that `is_anonymous()` will return `False` and `is_authenticated()` must return `True`.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. But the problem was that the username was to long and it was truncated to 30 characters. Found the answer here:

[Django Register Form 'AnonymousUser' object has no attribute 'backend'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7770848/django-register-form-anonymoususer-object-has-no-attribute-backend)

Comment: This is definitely not it.  The username is not that long.

Answer (score 0):

That happens when user was not authenticated. Be sure that you are using same field for loging Backend... for example I am loging with email (Backend that uses email and password) so

```
django.contrib.auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

if for me

```
django.contrib.auth.authenticate(username=email, password=password)
```

The backend is here: http://www.micahcarrick.com/django-email-authentication.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using replication in your database and happen to be reading from Read replica while writing to your master/default database, then if there is a replication lag that could also cause this. 
You will write to the master
while authenticate will try to read from read replica resulting in not finding the User.

The solution is to set up your routers to use default db for User queries.